# WPF Background Worker Error

Tags: wpf

```
// Worker Method
void _backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{     
    // Do something
    this.Progressbar1.Visibility=Visibility.Visible;
}
```

I have error on this can anyone Please help why this is error!

Comment: Expand your problem, a conflict of UI Tread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access to the UI from another thread. Use `Dispatcher`

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { this.Progressbar1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; }));
```

And for the next time post at least error description in your question. You will get the answer faster.